# Problema al tener la web en un directorio distinto a var/www/html

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Tengo un problema en apache2 montado en Ubuntu 18. Tengo el servidor apache2 con dos páginas con dominio en NO-IP. Me funcionan perfectamente si tengo los dos dominios en /var/www/html, pero yo quiero sacar una de ellas del directorio /var/www/html a otro directorio /home/Dropbox/PHP. La **seguridad no importa** ya que es para practicar ejercicios.
Entonces, cada vez que pongo mi IP o dominio de  NO-IP por ejemplo:
*http://60.000.000.000:8080/home/Dropbox/PHP*
Me sale el típico mensaje de:

> Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.

A ver yo el directorio /home/Drpbox/PHP lo tengo con permisos 777 ya que como he comentado la seguridad me da igual. Luego tengo el virtual host de esta manera:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/Dropbox/PHP
    ServerName xxxxxx.yyyy.net

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


        <Directory /home/Dropbox/PHP>
    Require all granted
        </Directory>
```

Luego en apache.conf añadi:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /home/Dropbox/PHP>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

No se que puedo estar haciendo mal. Pero cada vez que activo el segundo host, el que esta en el directorio /home/Dropbox/PHP me deniega el acceso a los dos host.

Comment: Con esa configuración intentas acceder a la ruta `/home/Dropbox/PHP/home/Dropbox/PHP`. Si quieres usar la ruta que pusiste en tu pregunta deberías tener `DocumentRoot /` pero en verdad un directorio raíz nunca debería ser público. Tu contenido lo debes encontrar en `http://60.000.000.000:8080/`.

Comment: Hola @Sal, pero que debo modificar. Mira yo creo que es un problema de permisos por que si pongo mi : http://miIp/Dropbox/PHP me sale que tengo el acceso prohibido por lo que me redirige bien apache2